# Show gamma-function $\Gamma(r)$ is well-defined for any $r >0$ (the limit of the improper definite integral exists)

Tags: probability, statistics, limits, probability-limit-theorems

**Introduction:**

I have proved the following:

Suppose that Poisson events are occuring at the constant rate of $\lambda$ per unit time. Let the random variable $Y$ denote the waiting time for the rth event, then $Y$ has pdf: $$f_Y(y) = \frac {\lambda^r} {(r-1)!} y^{r-1}e^{-\lambda y} $$ (1)

so $Y$ is defined for $r \in \mathbb N$.

However the gamma pdf:

$$f_Y(y) = \frac {\lambda^r} {\Gamma(r)} y^{r-1}e^{-\lambda y}$$

is a generalization of this function (right?), since $\Gamma(r) = (r-1)!$ for any positive integer $r$.

To justify that the gamma pdf is a well-defined function i must that the gamma function:

$$\Gamma(r) = \int_0^{\infty} y^{r-1}e^{-y} dy$$ is a well-defined function (I've already verified $$\int_0^{\infty}f_Y(y) dy = \int_0^{\infty} \frac {\lambda^r} {(r-1)!} y^{r-1}e^{-\lambda y} dy = 1$$ under the assumption that it is).

**Question:**

**1.**

How do I show that the gamma function is well-defined, that is the improper definite integral exists for any real number $r >0$ ? I know it exists for any positive integer $t > r$ (the integral with boundaries $0$ and $\infty$ of (1) is equal to $1$?) so $\Gamma(r) \le \Gamma(t)$ (right?) This implies that $\Gamma(r)$ is bounded, but how do I show the limit exists for $y \rightarrow \infty$ ? Also the functions of $y$ in $\Gamma(r)$ are both continuous, which implies the function is integrable ?

Comment: Begin by showing that $\Gamma(r+1) = r\Gamma(r)$.

Comment: Thank you, - and how to proceed afterwards ? How to evaluate when $\Gamma(r)$ and $0 < r < 1$ ?

Answer (score 2):

---

**Well defined:**
Let $s>0$. In this case, we have by definition that:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x} x^{s-1}dx:= \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0^+} \int_\delta^1 e^{-x} x^{s-1}dx+\lim_{A\rightarrow \infty }\int_1^Ae^{-x} x^{s-1} dx$$

To prove that these limits exist, we note we are dealing with positive functions and therefore, our integral is increasing as $\delta\rightarrow 0^+$ and $A\rightarrow \infty$. So they will converge to the respective supremums and it suffices to prove they are bounded! For the first integral it is easier to conjure an upper bound:

$$\int_\delta^{1}e^{-x}x^{s-1}dx\leq e^{-\delta} \int_\delta^{1}x^{s-1}dx=e^{-\delta}\frac{1-\delta ^s}{s}\leq \frac{1}{s}<\infty$$

For the second integral, an upper bound is slightly more difficult and we will separate our bound in two cases. If $-1<s-1\leq 0$ it is more straightforward because $x^{s-1}$ is non incresasing and we have:

$$\int_1^A e^{-x}x^{s-1}dx\leq \int_1^A e^{-x}dx=e^{-1}-e^{-A}\leq e^{-1}$$

Wen $s-1>0$, we need to use integration by parts to make it smaller! Namely, we have:

$$\int_1^A e^{-x}x^{s-1}dx=e^{-1}-A^{s-1}e^{-A}+(s-1)\int_1^A e^{-x}x^{s-1}dx\leq e^{-1}+(s-1)\int_1^A e^{-x}x^{(s-1)-1}dx  $$

We repeat integration by parts until $-1<s-k\leq 0$ in which case we get:

$$\int_1^A e^{-x}x^{s-1}dx\leq e^{-1}+(s-1)e^{-1}+(s-1)(s-2)e^{-1}+...+(s-1)...(s-k+1)\int_1^A e^{-x}x^{s-k} dx \leq $$
$$e^{-1}(1+(s-1)+(s-1)(s-2)+...+(s-1)...(s-k+1))<\infty$$

---

**Continuity:** Take $\epsilon>0$.Let $A(\epsilon, s_o)$ be so large that $\int_A^\infty e^{-x}x^{s_o+\epsilon-1}<\epsilon$, where $s_o$ and $\epsilon$ are fixed. Take $S$ such that $s_o\in[0,S]$ and let $f:[\epsilon,A]\times [0,S] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x,y)=x^{y-1}$. $f$ is continuous and we are in a compact domain hence it is uniformly continuos. Let $\delta'$ be such that if $|(x,s)-(x_o,s_o)|<\delta'<\min( \epsilon,s_o/2)$, $|x^{s-1}-x_o^{s_o-1}|<\epsilon$. In this case, if $|s-s_o|<\delta'$, we have:

$$\left|\int_0^\infty e^{-x}(x^{s-1}-x^{s_o-1})dx\right|\leq \left|\int_0^\epsilon e^{-x}(x^{s-1}-x^{s_o-1})dx\right|+\epsilon \int_\epsilon^A e^{-x}dx+\left|\int_A^\infty e^{-x}(x^{s-1 }-x^{s_o-1})dx\right|\leq \frac{\epsilon^s}{s}+\frac{\epsilon^{s_o}}{s_o}+\epsilon+2\epsilon\leq \frac{\epsilon^{s_o-\epsilon}+\epsilon^{s_o}}{s_o-\epsilon}+3\epsilon$$

Therefore, we have a continuous function as you correctly pointed out. The right-handside can be made as small as wanted if $\epsilon$ is taken to be small.